# Email notifications per JOB ARRAY not per job in PBS torque

Tags: torque, pbs

Is there a way to configure torque to send email notifications on start and end of job array, and not per job, Im managing job arrays of thousands of jobs, and I dont want to get flooded by mails. But indeed I want to know when the entire job array ends.